# Finding the longest sequence of equivalent values in a list?

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote a code about finding out the longest subsequence with the same number of a sequence of integers. The user enter a sequence of integers ending with 0 and the code does the rest, the code only works perfectly for small sequences, I cannot see where I went wrong. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test1 {

    private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int input;
    private static int counter = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a series of numbers ending with 0: ");

        boolean itsOk = true;
        while (itsOk) {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            list.add(input);

            if (input == 0)
                itsOk = false;
        }

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
            if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1))) {
                counter++;
                index = i - 2;
            }

        System.out.println("The longest same number sequence starts at index "
                + index + " with " + counter + " values of " + list.get(index));

        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("\tThe sorted series of numbers is : " + list);

    }
}
```

Comment: `"Why doesn't my code work nicely?"` -- just as an aside, please strive to make your question title more informative. Try to have it summarize your problem, not your frustration. Else you increase *our* frustration which is not good since we're volunteers.

Comment: As for your question itself, it's time to do some debugging with a debugger. You first must isolate and identify the bug before you can attempt to fix it.

Comment: You are close, but your code has too many logic errors to allow for a clear answer here. I also recommend examining your logic more closely, and using a debugger to help step through it. A general tip, by the way, when finding the maximum of something in a series of data, is to keep track of the current maximum and update as you encounter new maxima.

Comment: Why do you do `index = i - 2`? What if you only meet your condition when `i == 1`? Then `index` will be `-1`.

Comment: I'm not frustrated at all!! and Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This question got put on hold - in the future, you can avoid that by showing us not only your code and explaining your problem, but also by showing us some inputs that don't give you the output you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not keep track of which number your sub-sequence consists, nor the index of the sequence's beginning or its length. You need to keep track of these in separate variables.

As I said in a comment, `index = i - 2` can produce `index == -1`, so that's also right out.

Furthermore, your answer will be technically incorrect even after correcting these semantic errors because you are including the terminating `0` in your list, so be sure not to include it.

```
private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
private static int input;
private static int counter = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a series of numbers ending with 0: ");

    while (true) {
        input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input == 0) {
            break;  // don't add 0 to the list
        }
        list.add(input);
    }

    int index = 0;              // the current beginning of the sequence
    int currNum;                // the current candidate for the sequence num
    int theNum = list.get(0);   // keep track of the num with the longest sequence
    int theCount = 0;           // keep track of the count (length) of the longest sequence
    int theIndex = 0;           // keep track of where the sequence began
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        currNum = list.get(i-1);
        if (list.get(i).equals(currNum)) {
            if (counter == 1) {
                // note that a sequence is beginning, and its location
                index = i - 1;
            }
            counter++;
            if (counter > theCount) {
                // check if you've found a longer sequence
                theCount = counter;
                theNum = currNum;
                theIndex = index;
            }
        } else {
            // sequence broken, count from scratch
            counter = 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The longest same number sequence starts at index "
            + theIndex + " with " + theCount + " values of " + theNum);

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("\tThe sorted series of numbers is : " + list);

}
```

See the code run here on [ideone](http://ideone.com/AluaWp).

Comment: Clear and precise. Thank you for your help and your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use fixed values here :

```
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1))) {
            counter++;
            index = i - 2;
        }
```

`index = i-2` only works if the sequence is exactly 3 elements long.

Instead, you should create a variable to store the most recently seen value before the current one, and compare the current one to the value.  Additionally you should create a variable to store the length of the current sequence, and the length of the largest sequence already seen prior to the current sequence.  Only update 'index' if the current sequence length exceeds the previous sequence length.